# Maven: How to use properties from settings.xml via settings. prefix?

Tags: maven

When I add settings to settings.xml in this way...

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>outsorced-project-properties</id>
        <properties>
            <key.password>mysecretpassword</key.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>outsorced-project-properties</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
```

..then I can use ${key.password} with my project's pom.xml. This works but seems to be a little bit inconvenient.

In [MavenPropertiesGuide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide) thers is an information that you can use settings from settings.xml via settings. prefix.

> Local user settings
>
> Similarly, values in the user's settings.xml can be referenced using
>   property names with settings. prefix.
>
> ```
> ${settings.localRepository} refers to the path of the user's local repository
> ```

But this doesn't seem to work for me. At least I don't know how to define them within settings.xml. I tried to define them just within settings tag of settings.xml, or within a properties tag within the settings tags and so on, but the properties were never recognized. Did I understand anything wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can differentiate between the properties based on where they are defined. (i.e `${settings.key.password}` or `${settings.properties.key.password}` won't give you your password)

but if you are after the settings prefix, you can add the below to your settings file

```
<properties>
  <settings.password>mypassword</settings.password>
</properties>
```

and then refer it as `${settings.password}` in your pom files.

Comment: This doesn't work to work either. I tried it with <properties><settings.androidpath>/my/path</settings.androidpath></properties> in settings.xml and referenced it by ${settings.androidpath} or any combination but the problem is that Maven doesn't accept the properties tag itself within the settings.xml: `Unrecognised tag: 'properties'`

Comment: It does accept, but you have to honour the settings schema http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd . You can add the properties within a profile and make it active.

Comment: Works, so I vote you answer up although you don't even need the settings prefix. But it doesn't answer the question. It seems that there are 3 ways to defined properties^^

Comment: yes, the prefix is not at all required. You can use any property name. You can add properties in a profile in the settings file, directly in the pom, within a profile in the pom, in parent or grandparent... poms. Few of these are documented at http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html . And for the original question,it's not possible to refer all tags in the settings file using an xpath style property name. settings.localRepository should work though.